# Why can't I redirect grep output to file?

Tags: bash, grep, redirect

I am running command like this.

```
# ( ( partclone.restore -X -s some.img -o /dev/sda3 2>&3 ) 3>&1 ) | grep Completed
  Completed:  0.40%
  Completed:  1.23%
  Completed:  2.07%
  ...
```

But I cannot direct the output to a file.

```
# ( ( partclone.restore -X -s some.img -o /dev/sda3 2>&3 ) 3>&1 ) | grep Completed >> ./log 2>&1
```

There is nothing in the log file.

But something like `cat some.file | grep some.string >> ./log` works fine. Why?

Comment: What if you use `( partclone.restore -X -s some.img -o /dev/sda3 2>&3 ) 3>&1 ) | grep Completed >> ./log` ?

Comment: Could you try `( ( partclone.restore -X -s some.img -o /dev/sda3 2>&3 ) 3>&1 ) | grep Completed | tee ./log`

Comment: Neither of above comments work, I finally end up not using grep but just do "while read output" and do reg-ex on "output" to fetch the string.

Comment: It is working, the problem is when stdin/stdout aren't terminals, grep buffers the output, `grep --line-buffered` should work, see for instance http://stackoverflow.com/q/7161821/2774188